# Does ASIHTTP support multi threads?

Tags: iphone

Does ASIHTTP support multi thread?
If sure, I hope each thread link to aUIProgressbar, how can I construct the codes?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yups, ASIHttpRequest can handle more than on request at a time. See the help [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) and do notice this part.

> Using a queue
>
> This example does the same thing
>   again, but we've created an
>   NSOperationQueue for our request.
>
> Using an NSOperationQueue (or
>   ASINetworkQueue, see below) gives you
>   more control over asynchronous
>   requests. When using a queue, only a
>   certain number of requests can run at
>   the same time. If you add more
>   requests than the queue's
>   maxConcurrentOperationCount property,
>   requests will wait for others to
>   finish before they start.
>
> - (IBAction)grabURLInTheBackground:(id)sender
>     {    if (![self queue]) {
>       [self setQueue:[[[NSOperationQueue alloc]
>     init] autorelease]];    }
>      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
>     ASIHTTPRequest *request =
>     [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
>     [request setDelegate:self];
>     [request
>     setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
>     [request
>     setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
>     [[self queue] addOperation:request];
>     //queue is an NSOperationQueue }
> - (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {    NSString *response = [request responseString]; }
> - (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest
>     *)request {    NSError *error = [request error]; }
>
> In the above sample, ‘queue’ is a
>   retained NSOperationQueue property of
>   our controller.
>
> We’re setting custom selectors that
>   will be called when the request
>   succeeds or fails. If you don’t set
>   these, the defaults (requestFinished:
>   and requestFailed:) will be used, as
>   in the previous example.
>
> Handling success and failure for
>   multiple requests
>
> If you need to handle success and
>   failure on many different types of
>   request, you have several options:
>
> 1. If your requests are all of the same broad type, but you want to
>      distinguish between them, you can set
>      the userInfo NSDictionary property of
>      each request with your own custom data
>      that you can read in your finished /
>      failed delegate methods.
> 2. If you need to handle success and failure in a completely different
>      way for each request, set a different
>      setDidFinishSelector /
>      setDidFailSelector for each request
> 3. For more complex situations, or where you want to parse the response
>      in the background, create a minimal
>      subclass of ASIHTTPRequest for each
>      type of request, and override
>      requestFinished: and failWithProblem:.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 1):

Check out the sample code here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

It does support asynchronous requests (multithreaded) and you can use an ASINetworkQueue to monitor their progress.